# Scala macro to generate a class from a trait

Tags: scala, macros, mocking, metaprogramming

I'm looking for a way to generate a `class` from a `trait` with all the methods implemented (throwing `NotImplementedError`s). Having such class in place, I would be able to sub-class it to provide implementations for the methods I do need.

I consider this approach as a replacement for a mocking framework.

How to do that in scala-meta or scala-reflect?

Comment: do you want to do it at/before compile-time or in runtime?

Comment: @EvgenyVeretennikov compile-time, how else can I extend the generate the generated class?